# My scanf saves first character inputted by user, then the value saved in the next scanf

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


double f1( int size,
           float array1[] )
{
    double sum = 0;
    double meanAverage;

    int indexI;


    for ( indexI = 0;
          indexI < size;
          indexI++ )
    {
        sum = array1[ indexI ] + sum;
    }

    meanAverage = sum / size;
    printf( "%f", meanAverage);

    return meanAverage;
}

double f2( int size,
           float array1[] )
{
    double sum = 0;

    int indexI;


    for ( indexI = 0;
          indexI < size;
          indexI++ )
    {
        sum = array1[ indexI ] + sum;
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
    char * arrayA = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 20 );
    char * arrayB = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 20 );

    float * arrayC = malloc( sizeof( float ) * number );
    float * arrayD = malloc( sizeof( float ) * number );
    float * arrayE = malloc( sizeof( float ) * number );

    int choice;
    int choice_mean;
    int choice_sum;
    int indexI;
    int number;

    printf( "How many metals would you like to enter values for? "
            "Please enter a whole number.\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &number );

    for ( indexI = 0;
          indexI < number;
          indexI++ )
    {
        printf("Enter name of metal\n");
        scanf("%s",arrayA[i]);

        printf("Enter symbol of metal\n");
        scanf("%s",&arrayB[i]);

        printf("Enter atomic number of metal\n");
        scanf("%f",&arrayC[i]);

        printf("Enter atomic weight of metal\n");
        scanf("%f",&arrayD[i]);

        printf("Enter density of metal\n");
        scanf("%f",&arrayE[i]);
    }   

    for( indexI = 0;
         indexI < number;
         indexI++ )
    {
        printf( "%s,%s,%f,%f,%f\n",
                &arrayA[ indexI ],
                &arrayB[ indexI ],
                arrayC[ indexI ],
                arrayD[ indexI ],
                arrayE[ indexI ] );
    }

    printf( "Would you like to know the average or sum of these "
            "values, or see them listed again?  "
            "Enter 1 for average, 2 for sum, "
            "3 to see them again, 4 to exit\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &choice );

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 :
            printf("Enter 1 for atomic number, "
                   "2 for atomic weight,3 for density\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice_mean);

            switch( choice_mean )
            {
                case 1 :
                    f1( number,
                        arrayC );
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    f1( number,
                        arrayD );
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    f1( number,
                        arrayE );
                    break;
            }

            break;
        case 2 :
            printf( "1 for atomic number, 2 for atomic weight, 3 for density\n" );
            scanf( "%d",
                   &choice_sum );

            switch ( choice_sum )
            {
                case 1 :
                    f2( number,
                        arrayC );
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    f2( number,
                        arrayD );
                    break;
                case 3:
                    f2( number,
                        arrayE );
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3 :
            for( indexI = 0;
                 indexI < number;
                 indexI++ )
            {
                printf( "%s,%s,%f,%f,%f\n",
                        &arrayA[ indexI ],
                        &arrayB[ indexI ],
                        arrayC[ indexI ],
                        arrayD[ indexI ],
                        arrayE[ indexI ] );
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("You need to enter a number 1-4\n");
    }
}
```

This is the code for a program that is intended to take user input for a metal, the atomic symbol of this metal, atomic number, atomic weight, and density, print these values in tabular format, and ask the user if they want to know the mean average of the values of any of the columns with numbers in them, the sum of these numbers, if they want to see the table displayed again, or if they are finished, and it will do all the calculations and return them back to you.

My trouble is how to get my scanf not to require the `&` in front of it, because from what I have seen, that seems to be the cause of an error with my `scanf`, as it will take the first character of the first metal or symbol and then add the string of characters saved for the next metal or symbol to this for some reason.  I have looked online, and I am trying to find a way to change the `arrayA` so I can save the individual strings and finish up the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this even compile? `number` is used before declared in `main()`?

Comment: It compiles, they should be flipped. When I entered the code here,it flipped them when I entered it.